# Create a nested lists of categories in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

Am fairly new to Laravel and am trying to create a tree-like categories structure for my app. This is the code have I used to far but still unable to achieve what I want.
My controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $categories = Category::with('children')->get();

    return view('backend.categories.index')->with('categories', $categories);
}
```

My category model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'parent_id');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

My view:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Slug</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach ($categories as $category)
                    {{--@foreach ($category->children as $children)--}}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $category->name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $category->description }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $category->slug }}</td>
                        <td><a class="edit" href="{!! action('Admin\CategoriesController@edit', $category->id) !!}" title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></a></i> <a class="delete" href="{!! action('Admin\CategoriesController@destroy', $category->id) !!}" title="Are you sure you want to delete?"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></td>
                        @foreach ($category->children as $children)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ $children->name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $children->description }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $children->slug }}</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                    {{--@endforeach--}}
                @endforeach
            </table>
```

Am trying to produce a structure like below:

- Fashion Accessories

  - Bags
  - Cloths
- Mobile Phones

  - Tablets
  - Smartphones

EDIT
There is my database structure:

```
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| slug        | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| parent_id   | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| description | text             | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| created_at  | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| updated_at  | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: You are loading only Category data. Try --- $categories = Category::with(['parent','children'])->get();

Comment: True was only loading children but If I load both parent and children how do I use it in my view. Sorry for the lame question, am new to Laravel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently loading all categories (including the child ones) and then looping through them. You only want to load the root categories (categories without parent). To do this, change your controller method to only load categories where the `parent_id` is `null`.

```
$categories = Category::whereNull('parent_id')->with('children')->get();
```

Comment: how do I loop through in my view file

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, this works perfectly just the way I wanted.

Comment: Am now faced with how to produce a select menu with the categories in category edit form...any help on this?

Comment: Just a list of all categories? You can get those with `Category::all()`. You might want to start a new question for this.

Answer (score 0):

Probably in model you need to change inorder to refer to children model:

```
public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Children', 'parent_id');
    }
```

Model for category:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $fillable = array('name','description','slug','created_at','updated_at');

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Children', 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

Model for childrens:

```
class Children extends Model {
     protected $table = 'children';
     protected $fillable = array('name','description','parent_id','created_at','updated_at');
}
```

In controller get categories with children like this:

```
$categories = Category::with(['children'])->get();
```

and correct the tags -- `<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a>`

then in the view:

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)              
       <ul>
           <li>{{ $category->name }}</li>
           <li>{{ $category->description }}</li>
           <li>{{ $category->slug }}</li>
           <li><a class="edit" href="{!! action('Admin\CategoriesController@edit', $category->id) !!}" title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a> <a class="delete" href="{!! action('Admin\CategoriesController@destroy', $category->id) !!}" title="Are you sure you want to delete?"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></li>


               @foreach ($category->children as $children)
                  <ul>
                    <li>{{ $children->name }}</li>
                    <li>{{ $children->description }}</li>
                    <li>{{ $children->slug }}</li>
                    <li></li>
                  </ul>
               @endforeach

       </ul>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Tried it but children categories are still listed as stand alone (i.e parent)

Comment: Could you explain  --- still listed as stand alone

Comment: Do you have a model for the table children? Is there a column in the table children which refers to the table category(forange key)

Comment: By stand alone, I mean the children categories are listed as parent categories after they have been listed under their coresponding parent

Comment: am using 1 model which is the Category model. I have edit my question to include the database structure of the Category model

Comment: You should have a model for each table. Are you able to fetch childrens data without childrens model???